# Is there any way to make a function run before a dataSource fucntion?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, function, datasource

I am trying to access information from Firebase via a dataSource function, but the dataSource function always runs before the information has been obtained. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a dataSource delegate method to supply data to a tableview, for example. Before you have received the data via Firebase, you have nothing to supply, so your tableview will be empty.

Make the Firebase request, and when its data arrives, you update the data that the datasource delegate accesses, and then you reload the table view.

Comment: What would the code look like to update the data that the datasource delegate accesses, and how would I reload the table vie? Thank you for your help.